# C++, How to escape special characters from argv without the user manually adding escape characters

Tags: c++, parsing, escaping, argv

I'm writing a program in C++ that can take several input arguments like so:

**Edit:** based on suggestions from comments

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
constants c;
for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    if ( (argv[i])[0] == '-') {
        if ((argv[i])[1] == 'h'){
            bHelp = true;
            //spit out some help text here
        }
        else if ((argv[i])[1] == 'c' && (argv[i+1]) != nullptr){
            c.host = argv[i+1];
        }
        else if ((argv[i])[1] == 'd' && (argv[i+1]) != nullptr){
            c.databasename = argv[i+1];
        }
        else if ((argv[i])[1] == 'w' && (argv[i+1]) != nullptr){
            c.password = argv[i+1];
        }
        else if ((argv[i])[1] == 'u' && (argv[i+1]) != nullptr){
            c.username = argv[i+1];
        }
        else if ((argv[i])[1] == 'p' && (argv[i+1]) != nullptr){
            c.port = argv[i+1];
        }
    }
}
if (bHelp) {exit(1);}
```

When run the program seems to work properly, so far so good I thought.

However if any of the input following the flags has special characters for instance a '#' the program segfaults on start.

Whilst you can still make it work by manually escaping such characters on start, with "./app -u testuser -w \#fakepass" for example.

I would rather not bother my end-user with such things and would prefer to solve it in the code.

Comment: That's a feature of your shell, not the program itself.

Comment: This has nothing to do with character escaping. You'll get the same segfault if you completely fail to provide the parameter to your option. Fix the bug in your code that's segfaulting.

Comment: Off topic You may find reading up on `else` and `switch` helpful. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if , http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Thanks for pointing that out, its test code and I hadn't noticed, I'll just google on how to check for special chars so i can check before assigning it to the c.password (and ofc check if theres anything at all)

Comment: @user4581301, I was using switch before, but to me personally this is more legible

Comment: In that case, I recommend the `else`. `argv[i])[1]` cannot be h, c, d, w, q, and p all at the same time, so why bother always testing all of the cases?

Comment: @user4581301, fair point

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, your right, since # starts a comment block theres no way to handle this in the program itself, if you make this an answer ill accept it.

Comment: It seems that instead of command line arguments in this particular case it might be better to just parse a config file instead, atleast that way I dont have to bother the enduser